# Varnish Cache not working Magento 2.3, nginx proxy and apache2 backend webservers

Tags: magento2.3, cache, nginx, varnish, apache2

I have a site setup with nginx as proxy serving an apache2 server, I'm trying to implement varnish caching.

nginx is listening on 443 and 80
varnish is configured to listen on 8080
apache2 is configured to listen on 7081 and 8081

My etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf

```
    #ATTENTION!
    #
    #DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
    #SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
    
    include "/etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/ip_default/*.conf";
    
    server {
            listen 77.68.81.77:443 ssl;
            listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl;


    
            ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/cert8arxYuY;
            ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/cert8arxYuY;
    
            location ^~ /plesk-site-preview/ {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                    proxy_set_header Host               plesk-site-preview.local;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
                    proxy_cookie_domain plesk-site-preview.local $host;
                    access_log off;
            }
    
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://77.68.81.77:8080;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }
    
    server {
            listen 77.68.81.77:80;
            listen 127.0.0.1:80;


            location ^~ /plesk-site-preview/ {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                    proxy_set_header Host               plesk-site-preview.local;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
                    proxy_cookie_domain plesk-site-preview.local $host;
                    access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://77.68.81.77:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

My etc/default/varnish :-

```
DAEMON _OPTS="-a :8080\
  -T localhost:6082 \
  -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
  -s malloc,256m"
  -S /etc/varnish/secret
```

My etc/varnish/default.vcl file the remainder of which is what is generated via magento admin *** NOW IN FULL ***:

```
    # VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8081";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

My /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :8080 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1G
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and results of netstat -tulpn

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1528/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      950/named           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12346         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1528/master         
tcp        0      0 77.68.81.77:443         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3616/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995/sw-cp-server: m 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58013           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      892/rpc.mountd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12768         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      957/psa-pc-remote   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44997           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      892/rpc.mountd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53831           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      892/rpc.mountd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1372/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1528/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      673/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 77.68.81.77:80          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3616/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8880            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995/sw-cp-server: m 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1528/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38897           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 77.68.81.77:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      950/named           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      950/named           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      786/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1004/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1528/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      995/sw-cp-server: m 
tcp6       0      0 :::4190                 :::*                    LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6082                :::*                    LISTEN      7220/varnishd       
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::36519                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::7081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1193/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::37833                :::*                    LISTEN      892/rpc.mountd      
tcp6       0      0 :::106                  :::*                    LISTEN      1066/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      1528/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      942/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::55215                :::*                    LISTEN      892/rpc.mountd      
tcp6       0      0 :::39791                :::*                    LISTEN      892/rpc.mountd      
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      673/rpcbind         
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      7220/varnishd       
tcp6       0      0 :::8880                 :::*                    LISTEN      995/sw-cp-server: m 
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      1528/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1193/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      1066/xinetd         
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      950/named           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1004/sshd           
udp        0      0 77.68.81.77:53          0.0.0.0:*                           950/named           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           950/named           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           786/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           791/dhclient        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           673/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:849             0.0.0.0:*                           673/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38403           0.0.0.0:*                           892/rpc.mountd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34749           0.0.0.0:*                           892/rpc.mountd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56141           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44182           0.0.0.0:*                           892/rpc.mountd      
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                950/named           
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                673/rpcbind         
udp6       0      0 fe80::250:56ff:fe07:546 :::*                                836/dhclient        
udp6       0      0 :::849                  :::*                                673/rpcbind         
udp6       0      0 :::58393                :::*                                892/rpc.mountd      
udp6       0      0 :::34424                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::51490                :::*                                892/rpc.mountd      
udp6       0      0 :::57200                :::*                                892/rpc.mountd
```

However when I test the response with curl i get:-

curl request is

```
curl -I https://www.bubit.co.uk
```

response is :-

```
HTTP/2 404 
server: nginx
date: Thu, 14 May 2020 15:09:10 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.30
pragma: cache
cache-control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
expires: Fri, 15 May 2020 15:09:09 GMT
x-magento-tags: cat_c,cat_c_3,cat_c_13,cat_c_11,cat_c_12,cat_c_14,store,cms_b,cms_p_1
x-magento-debug: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=erq8fgjfr2fup10jea83ss5ug4; expires=Thu, 14-May-2020 16:09:09 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.bubit.co.uk; HttpOnly
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
```

Which isn't showing varnish headers

running :

```
curl -k -I https://77.68.81.77
```

returns:-

```
HTTP/2 302 
server: nginx
date: Fri, 15 May 2020 10:17:19 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.30
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
expires: Wed, 15 May 2019 10:17:19 GMT
x-magento-debug: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=mq5bjb3nt4rk1qgsnmgkq5tnsd; expires=Fri, 15-May-2020 11:17:19 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=77.68.81.77; HttpOnly
location: https://www.bubit.co.uk/?SID=mq5bjb3nt4rk1qgsnmgkq5tnsd
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
x-powered-by: PleskLin
```

running:-

```
curl -I http://77.68.81.77:80
```

returns:-

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 15 May 2020 10:19:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://77.68.81.77/
```

this:-

```
curl -I http://77.68.81.77:8081
```

returns:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 May 2020 10:23:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 15:29:12 GMT
ETag: "2aa6-58b0df577dd48"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 10918
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
above 3 seem to be normal
```

however the following:-

```
curl -I http://77.68.81.77:8080
```

returns:-

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed
Date: Fri, 15 May 2020 10:21:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Retry-After: 5
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Does that mean that the backend link to apache isn't working or that there is no cache of the page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Chris

Comment: take note of `proxy_pass https://77.68.81.77:8080;` - Varnish open source cannot do TLS. (the `https://` is definitely wrong)

Comment: @DanilaVershinin well spotted changed it and restarted everything but still no response from varnish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thijs Feryn,

Thanks for all your help, pushed me it the right direction, when I looked at the default.vcl that is generated by magento it actually strips out the response headers from varnish so i just remarked them out and I now get the X-Varnish response in the headers

```
#unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
#unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
#unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
#unset resp.http.Server;
#unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
#unset resp.http.Via;
#unset resp.http.Link;
```

Thanks Again

Comment: This crossed my mind, but I never thought these headers would actually be stripped off. Another big indicator is the `Age` header, but because of the *Backend Fetch Error*, the `Age` header was probably not set either. Glad to see you managed to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

### More information needed

The `curl` request only displays the response. I'd like to see request information as well, to figure out which URL you called.

The VCL file is truncated as well. It's not complete and I'm not 100% sure whether or not the Varnish headers are stripped through VCL.

However it seems unlikely that these headers are stripped.

### Use Varnishlog

You could run the following command to see if there's traffic coming through Varnish:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -i requrl
```

This command will display the URL of each request that is accepted by Varnish.

### Use systemd instead

Your `/etc/default/varnish` doesn't really matter, because *systemd* is responsible for the runtime options of Varnish.

This setting will be the active one:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :8081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1G
```

You can just edit it using `sudo systemctl edit --full varnish.service`. After you set `-a :8080`, you save and exit.

In the next step you run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to reload systemd and `sudo systemctl restart varnish` to make sure Varnish is restarted. After that it should work.

### The `-F` flag

Another piece of advice is to remove the `-F` flag, because that will run Varnish on the foreground. You might want to have a look at https://gist.github.com/ThijsFeryn/2c4913b96a428cfbd8cde15c03fa12b3 for a typical systemd service file for Varnish.

You can still set the port & memory settings the way you want, but some other details you can borrow from my config.

### Socket in use

The error below that you stated is pretty normal:

```
Error: Could not get socket :80: Address already in use
```

If you run `varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl` without any `-a` settings, Varnish will just accept connections on port 80, which will clash with Nginx that already has port 80 assigned to its process.

### What to do next

It seems very weird that a regular request through port 80 or 443 doesn't work. Your process list indicates that all service are running on the desired ports.

What I would do if I were you is the following:

- Edit the Varnish runtime config via `sudo systemctl edit --full varnish`
- Make sure all parameters are tuned correctly
- `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to reload systemd
- `sudo systemctl restart varnish` to restart Varnish
- `sudo systemctl restart nginx` to restart Nginx

The good old "turning it off & on again" trick.

### Testing all ports

Another piece of advice I have for you is to test all related ports on the server, by running a bunch of curl commands.

```
curl -k -I https://localhost
curl -I http://localhost:80
curl -I http://localhost:8080
curl -I http://localhost:8081
```

This will allow you to see which ports are listening and what headers you're getting back from each endpoint. Maybe that will help you debug.

Comment: [@Thijs Feryn] added the requested information, the active version of the varnish.service was already set to port 8080, i restarted everything and still not getting a response from varnish Chris

Comment: @ChrisGrierson I edited my answer and added a section about testing all ports. Maybe that will help you figure out what's going on. I'm assuming Apache, Nginx & Varnish are all running on the same server. Please give it a go.

Comment: added responses from curl commands looks normal apart from the varnish response any ideas?

Comment: Varnish returns a `503 backend fetch failed error` because the backend is unhealthy. This is caused by the health check probe in the backend to return an `HTTP 500` for `https://www.bubit.co.uk/pub/health_check.php`

Comment: managed to get the correct response back from health_check now but still getting the same response from curl -I http://www.bubit.co.uk:8080 503 backend fetch error

Comment: Changed the default.vcl file and now getting a 200 response from the curl but varnish still not caching or returning response